# Can you charge for the ability to annotate texts which you are using it under a non-commercial license, where you still show the text for free?

Tags: copyright, commerce

Say a bible text is released with a creative commons non-commercial license (can't use for commercial purposes). Say I then publish that text and make it freely available under the same license, so customers get it for free without any commercial business. Can I then charge to add the ability to annotate the text, or do other user-oriented things with the text (ability to bookmark texts, ability to comment on them, compare them, etc.)? To me the text is still available for free and so isn't being charged for, but it is the extra features which are being charged for. Or does that count as commercial use?

If it counts as commercial use, then I assume hosting ads on the site would also count as commercial use, and that even linking to the text in social media, the purpose of which is to raise awareness to buy related content (like public domain physical books made from some content related to the commercial-okay licensed few things) would also count as commercial use, and any tangentially related "commercial" activity. Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

### The Bible is public domain

There is no copyright so there is no licence.